# Pyomo assignes floats to Integer domain

Tags: python, integer, unique, pyomo, ipopt

Having a simplified problem: I'd like to assign an instance ID anywhere in in the `instance_map`. The goal is to have the ID's uniquely distributed over the instance_map, so each ID should occur exatcly once.

Pyomo in turn raises that this task is unfeasbile and most surprisingly started assigning with floats in an integer domain. Here's the code

```
import pyomo.environ as pe

model = pe.ConcreteModel()

model.rows = pe.RangeSet(1, 2)
model.cols = pe.RangeSet(1, 5)
model.instances = pe.RangeSet(1, 5)
model.n_instances = pe.Var(initialize=5)
model.n_cols = pe.Var(initialize=5)
model.n_rows = pe.Var(initialize=2)

model.instances_map = pe.Var(model.rows, model.cols, within=pe.Integers, initialize=0, bounds=(0, model.n_instances.value))

def unique_instances_check(model, instance):
    if instance == 0:
        return sum(model.instances_map[i,j] == instance for i in model.rows for j in model.cols) >= 0
    else:
        return sum(model.instances_map[i,j] == instance for i in model.rows for j in model.cols) == 1
model.C1 = pe.Constraint(model.instances, rule=unique_instances_check)

def objective(model):
    return sum(model.instances_map[1,j] for j in model.cols)
model.obj = pe.Objective(rule=objective, sense=pe.minimize)

opt = pe.SolverFactory("ipopt").solve(model)
model.instances_map.pprint()
```

When running it I get the the following output for the last code line

```
WARNING: Loading a SolverResults object with a warning status into
    model.name="unknown";
      - termination condition: infeasible
      - message from solver: Ipopt 3.14.5\x3a Converged to a locally
        infeasible point. Problem may be infeasible.
instances_map : Size=10, Index=instances_map_index
    Key    : Lower : Value             : Upper : Fixed : Stale : Domain
    (1, 1) :     0 : 5.000000049983252 :     5 : False : False : Integers
    (1, 2) :     0 : 5.000000049983252 :     5 : False : False : Integers
    (1, 3) :     0 : 5.000000049983252 :     5 : False : False : Integers
    (1, 4) :     0 : 5.000000049983252 :     5 : False : False : Integers
    (1, 5) :     0 : 5.000000049983252 :     5 : False : False : Integers
    (2, 1) :     0 : 5.000000049983252 :     5 : False : False : Integers
    (2, 2) :     0 : 5.000000049983252 :     5 : False : False : Integers
    (2, 3) :     0 : 5.000000049983252 :     5 : False : False : Integers
    (2, 4) :     0 : 5.000000049983252 :     5 : False : False : Integers
    (2, 5) :     0 : 5.000000049983252 :     5 : False : False : Integers
```

I was expecting many 0 assignments but 1,2,3,4,5 only once.

I'm honestly not sure where to go from here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your problem is not converging to a feasible point, so there is no guarantee that the returned solution respects any constraints or bounds.

More importantly, `ipopt` is a continuous interior point solver and ignores discrete domains.  If you look at the solver output (by adding `tee=True'` to the `solve` call), you should see:

```
==> Warning: Treating __ binary and __ integer variables as continous.
```

at the top of the solver output log.

Comment: I see, so that explaints the floats many thanks on that. But why pyomo refuses to assign the instances ? I added a dummy optimization goal as that's what I understood was missing piece but the result is the same (If I'd switch to `mindtpy` it's the same)